# Django unused import statement: virtualenv issue

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I have looked all over and nobody seems to be having the same issue as me. I am new to Django and have followed many tutorials but nothing is working. Before I found out that it is best practice to setup a virtualenv for your django projects I had installed it normally (globally) on my pc (ubuntu) and everything worked fine. I wanted to follow best practice though and started fresh and setup a project in a virtualenv. The landing page works and everything, but when I go to and editor I get errors wherever imports using django are.

Example:
Project->polls app->views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

Error given: 
Unused import statement
But also:
unresolved import 'django.shortcuts' Python (unresolved import)
```

I am completely lost at this point. I really would love to start using Django but I really want to follow best practice with virtualenv. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I have gotten it to work in pycharm. It seems as if the path to this project is automatically recognized now in pycharm but not vs code. Wanted to use vscode but it only lets me use the default path to python 3.x.x .

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: Have tried multiple (vs code and Pycharm, same issue for both)

Comment: `Unused import statement` means let's take your example, here you have not used the  `render` function in this entire python file, just call it later in the code and I guess it would solve your issue

Comment: Unresolved import 'django.shortcuts' 
Is another error I get. It is not recognizing it at all

Comment: I checked the version of Django as well (inside the project folder) to make sure it was installed:
python -m django --version
2.2.6

Comment: I have found a link to docs of VS Code to solve the issue, and included in my answer, check if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the pycharm interpreter to point to your virtualenv.

How to do that:

```
1. Go to file-> settings -> Project:your_project_name -> Project Interpreter
 2. On the right you can see a circle gear, click on it and select 'Add local'
 3. In the next page that opens, on left click Virtual Environment, then in radio-button 
    click Existing environment.
 4. On Interpreter box right side, select the three dots, select the /path/to/virtualenv/Scripts/python.exe
```

Next click OK and on next box Apply, now the errors should have gone.

Please check out the instructions on their [pycharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) as well they also suggest the same.

**For VS Code**:
Check out the docs here: [Using Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there's something wrong with your virtual environment. You should activate your virtual environment.If your virtual environment is activated  it's name should be in your terminal inside braces.